# How do you listen for custom events in Polymer Dart 1.0?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I've been trying to do something like the following inside a Polymer Dart 1.0 element

```
@PolymerRegister('some-element')
class SomeElement extends PolymerElement {
    ...
    void fireEvent() {
        fire('someevent');
    }
    ...
}
```

I then listen for it in this manner

```
<some-element on-someevent="handleSomeEvent"></some-element>
```

with the method defined inside the Polymer Element that I'm using  in defined thus

```
@reflectable
void handleSomeEvent([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is I get an

```
Unhandled exception
```

which wasn't helpful, and it took me a while to figure out that the above was causing it.  If I remove the

```
@reflectable
```

annotation from the event handler method, I get the following

```
method `registered` not defined
```

I was wondering if there is a special way to handle custom events in Polymer Dart 1.0?

I can handle it this way

```
on['someevent'].listen(handleSomeEvent);
```

which does work, it's just I don't see why I shouldn't be able to handle it both ways.  I'm thinking I'll be submitting a bug report on this, but I thought I'd put it here and check to see if I've done this correctly, since what I did, apart from using

@reflectable

which is Polymer Dart 1.0 specific, is what they say you should do in Polymer JS whose documentation can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#declarative-handlers)

UPDATE
I should clarify, this exception happened at load time, when the element was being registered.  I'll put the full exception in later, when I have a bit more time.

The exception I'm getting is the following

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: Unhandled exception:
Reflecting on un-marked type 'JsObjectImpl'
#0      _InstanceMirrorImpl._InstanceMirrorImpl (package:reflectable/src/reflectable_transformer_based.dart:150:9)
#1      ReflectableImpl.reflect (package:reflectable/src/reflectable_transformer_based.dart:1216:16)
#2      _setupReflectableMethods.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_descriptor.dart:151:49)
#3      JsObject._callMethod (dart:js:678)
#4      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:618)
#5      PolymerRegister.initialize (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_register.dart:19:13)
#6      loadInitializers.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/src/static_loader.dart:46:32)
#7      _runInitQueue (package:initialize/initialize.dart:35:24)
#8      _runInitQueue.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/initialize.dart:38:26)
#9     _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1165)
#10     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:502)
#11     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:585)
#12     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:376)
#13     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:430)
#14     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#15     _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#16     _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:42565)
Stack Trace:
#0      JsObject._callMethod (dart:js:678)
#1      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:618)
#2      PolymerRegister.initialize (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_register.dart:19:13)
#3      loadInitializers.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/src/static_loader.dart:46:32)
#4      _runInitQueue (package:initialize/initialize.dart:35:24)
#5      _runInitQueue.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/initialize.dart:38:26)
#6      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1165)
#7      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:502)
#8      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:585)
#9      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:376)
#10     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:430)
#11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#12     _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#13     _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:42565)
```

## Further Info

Next time I ask for help, I'll just use the exact code I'm using.  The method I'm annotating with

```
@reflectable
```

is called registered.

```
@reflectable
void registered([_, __]) {
    ....
}
```

If I change the name of this method to something else like

```
@reflectable
void someOtherName([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

The exception doesn't occur.  Sorry about that, it didn't occur to me the name of the method might have something to do with it.  Again sorry, but I still would like some explanation as to why the name of the annotated method matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is just fine.

```
@reflectable
void handleSomeEvent([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

Can you provide the project in a GitHub repo that allows to reproduce the problem?

An additional method would be

```
@Listen('someevent')
void handleSomeEvent([_, __]) {
    ...
}
```

(You don't need to add anything to HTML for this method).

Comment: I don't have a project on Github yet, that reproduces the problem. I'll put one up later today. I'll have a look at the @Listen annotation as well, but my original method should have worked.

Comment: Definitely, your original method should work. I guess the exception was thrown by the code inside the method, not by Polymer. The exception after you removed `@reflectable` is expected.

Comment: Ah no, it not the code inside the method, as I removed all the code except a print statement, and it still threw the exception.  I should clarify, this exception happened at load time.

Comment: I see. I'll wait for the reproducible project. It's too difficult to tell without all the information.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/terrasea/gcanvas.  I'm still in the process of updating it to use Polymer Dart 1.0.0 and the two elements that are relevant in this case are gcanvas-app and gcanvas-registration.  I think it's specific to this project as I tried reproducing it in a new project and it worked like a charm.  That's of course after I downgraded the version of analyzer, which the latest version is causing some major headaches for me, but that's another problem

Comment: I think I have a major clue here.  The name of the method I'm using is registered, and if I change it to something else, it doesn't throw the exception

Comment: Cheers for that. Saves me from submitting a bug report myself. :-)

Comment: Yeah what an obscure one to.

Comment: Ah yes, definitely a weird one. What is actually happening here is that `registered` is a special method which gets invoked at element registration time. Unfortunately `this` at that time is the polymer element descriptor object, which is a JsObject, not an instance of the actual element. We should probably just give an error or something if you try to use that method name (or if you mark it with @reflectable at least).